# Load multiple query result rows into array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I'm creating a RPG. When the user logs in, I want to load their data from three tables:

- **quest_items** stores all data related to an item:
- **join_questitems** stores association between player ID and the items that player has:
- **userstats** stores user_id, current map, current quest, x y location, etc

Since I want to load all this data on runtime, I figured I'd just put the two queries in the same function, store results in separate arrays, then push those two arrays into `allData` array. Then encode `allData` and pass it back to JS.

The problem here is accessing the data in the `$.(each` loop:

---

**PHP:**

```
$allData = array();
$itemsArray = array();
$statsArray = array();

$qry = 
    'SELECT qi.* 
    FROM quest_items qi
    LEFT JOIN join_questitems jqi ON (qi.item_id = jqi.item_id)
    WHERE jqi.user_id = "' . $playerID . '"';

$result = $mysqli->query($qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $itemsArray[] = $row;
}   

$qry = 
    'SELECT us.* 
    FROM userstats us
    WHERE us.id_user_fk = "' . $playerID . '"';

$result = $mysqli->query($qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $statsArray[] = $row;
}   

array_push($allData, $itemsArray, $statsArray);

echo json_encode($allData);
```

**JavaScript snippet:**

I'm able to access the first array (`$itemsArray`) within `$allData` with `v[0].item_name` from **quest_items** table, which gives: `rice, test/path.png` as expected.

But if I try to access the second array `v[1].username` from **userstats** table, it gives `undefined`.

```
$.getJSON("phpscripts.php", {
    "_player" : Player,
    "_playerID" : UserID
},
function(returned_data) {                       
    $.each(returned_data, function (key, value) {       
        $(".questItems").append("<br/>" + value[1].username + ", " + value[0].item_name);   
    });
```

- `value[1].username` = undefined
- `value[0].item_name` = works

This is curious because the chrome debugger response shows that both arrays are being added and returned inside the container array:

[image]

Why is this? Why can't I access array 2 with `value[1].username`?

---

EDIT:

```
$.each(returned_data, function (key, value) {               
    console.log(value[1]);  
});
```

Gives:

```
Object {item_id: "2", item_name: "meat", item_chinese: "rou", ...   (index):29
undefined (index):29
```

Which is a result set from `value[0]`. Maybe what's happening is either

- since `value[0]` has more result rows than does `value[1]`, maybe it's looping through again for `value[1]` even though it is passed its array size. Would that break it?
- `value[1]` is actually accessing the second array value from the first items array... and not pointing to the **userstats** array?

---

EDIT 2:

`console.log(returned_data)` right after `function(returned_data)` gives:

```
[Array[2], Array[1]]
0: Array[2]
1: Array[1]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

`console.log(value);` right after `$.each(returned_data, function (key, value) {` **gives:**

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]

[Object]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

**Expanded** results of `console.log(returned_data);` after  `function(returned_data)`:

[image]

---

EDIT 3: It works if I manually access the array: `returned_data[1][0]["username"]`

```
function(returned_data) {
    console.log(returned_data[1][0]["username"]); //DAN
    console.log(returned_data[0][0]["item_name"]); //rice
    console.log(returned_data[0][1]["item_name"]); //meat
```

But what if I have a lot of data rows to return for item_name. I need a loop to get all data.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(v[1]);`? Is `v[1].item_name` meat?

Comment: Where are you setting `v`? It seems it's already diving into the `0` of the container. Use better variable names than `v`. :)

Comment: @HamzaKubba see update. V is the value I'm setting in $.each. and yes, `v[1].item_name` is meat

Comment: `console.log(returned_data)` right after `function(returned_data) {`, and `console.log(value)` right after `$.each(returned_data, function (key, value) {`

Comment: And although `value` is better than `v`, something descriptive like `userData` or `userRawData` would bring more clarity to the code (not required by any means).

Comment: You have 2 separate arrays. Are you trying to access both arrays? It looks like the objects in 2 arrays do no have both of those both of those properties item_name and username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time the function passed to `$.each()` runs, `value` is the `0` subcontainer which has `0` and `1`. The second time the function runs, `value` is the `1` subcontainer already.

If `returned_data[0]` and `returned_data[1]` are different and you want to do different things with them, don't use `$.each()`, just use `returned_data[0]` and `returned_data[1]`.

So:

```
$.each(returned_data[0], function (key, value) {       
    $(".questItems").append("<br/>" + returned_data[1][0].username + ", " + value[0].item_name);   
});
```

Comment: Okay I realize this. How can I accomplish getting the results from two arrays passed from a containing PHP array with $.each loop?

Comment: Updated with that... don't use `$.each()`, use `returned_data[0]` and `returned_data[1]`.

Comment: Or maybe `returned_data[0][0]` and `returned_data[1][0]`.

Again, it's better to give names rather than `0` and `1`, so you don't get confusing data.

Comment: those are array indexes - not variable names

Comment: They would still work, but you can do `returned_data[0][0+""]` and `returned_data[1][0+""]` if you want to be a stickler for detail. That said, JS recognizes that `returned_data[0]` and `returned_data[1]` are objects, and converts the last `0` to a string before looking it up.

Comment: @HamzaKubba how can I loop through them then if I have a lot of data results for something like item_name? See above `Edit 3`

Comment: You want to loop on `returned_data[0]`. And you want the contents of `returned_data[1][0]` (with no looping).

Comment: @HamzaKubba I just did that just after I asked the question. Thanks :) It works